# Proving Green's Reciprocity theorem

Tags: electrostatics, classical-electrodynamics

This is problem number 50 from the third chapter of potentials from Griffiths:

Two charge distributions, $\rho_1(\textbf{r})$ produces a potential $V_1(\mathbf{r})$ and some other charge distribution $\rho_2(\mathbf{r})$ produces a potential $V_2(\mathbf{r})$. We are asked to prove $$\int_\limits{\mathit{all \,space}} \rho_1 V_1\, d\tau = \int_\limits{{all \, space}} \rho_2 V_1 \, d\tau$$
Which is known as "Green's reciprocity theorem"

Here's what I did and the author suggested

We can write$$\int \vec{E_1}\cdot\vec{E_2} \,d\tau$$ in two different ways by writing $\vec{E} = -\nabla{V}$

So using the product rule and integrating by parts I arrive at $$\ -\oint_\mathcal{S} V_1 \vec{E_2} \cdot d \vec{a} \, + \int_\mathcal{V} V_1 \frac{\rho_2}{\epsilon_0} d\tau=\ -\oint_\mathcal{S} V_2 \vec{E_1} \cdot d \vec{a} \, + \int_\mathcal{V} V_2 \frac{\rho_1}{\epsilon_0} d\tau $$

Now I make this argument: "Integrating over all space will make the surface integrals vanish as both $V_1, V_2 \to 0$ for an arbitrarily large volume." I'm unsure about this as the charge distribution may themselves go on to infinity(?) In that case the integrals won't vanish, I think. Is this argument correct?

Also I would like to ask if Green's reciprocity theorem is simply a mathematical coincidence (which seems unlikely to me) or does it also have any physical significance as well.

Also I'm a high school senior graduating in a few months aspiring to be  a physicist. I'm reading EM by Griffiths and was wondering if there are any other good reads that I can check out. I'm willing to work hard to understand the subject. I have read vector calculus only up to Griffiths level but I will brush that up if needed.

Comment: i am partial to Panofsky-Phillips: Classical Electricity and Magnetism, see:  https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.350495/page/n17/mode/2up (there is also a newer edition)

Comment: thanks ill do check it out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $\rho(r)$ will always be a "well behaved" function, your argument for the surface integral is good.

Moreover we can see the physical meaning of Green's reciprocity theorem looking at the following situation: suppose that we have only one charge in a region $a$ such that

$$ Q_a = \int_a\rho_1d\tau = Q\qquad Q_b = \int_b\rho_2 d\tau=0 $$

now the charge $Q_a=Q$ produces a potential where the charge $Q_b$ would be placed $V_{1b}\equiv V_{ab}$. Now we do the converse, turn off charge $Q_a$ and turn on charge $Q_b$ such that they produce the same charge $Q$

$$ Q_a = \int_a\rho_1d\tau = 0 \qquad Q_b = \int_b\rho_2d\tau = Q$$

This charge $Q_b=Q$ produces a potential where the charge $Q_a$ would be placed $V_{2a}\equiv V_{ba}$ since they are generated by the same amount of charge $Q$. Using Green's reciprocity theorem we conclude that

$$QV_{ab} = QV_{ba}\implies V_{ab}=V_{ba}$$

which is exactly what we would physically expect.

For the second question, although usually you shouldn't ask more than one question, i would recommend Jackson's *Classical Electrodynamics*. It's the bible of the classical theory of EM. As well as Landau's books *Classical theory of fields* and *Electrodynamics of Continuous Media*. All of them, especially Jackson's book, are quite heavy with the mathematics, they go far beyond vector calculus. But give them a look and judge by yourself.

Comment: thank you for the help!

Comment: @U.Basumatary You're welcome! If you feel like this answered your question you should accept it with the check-mark!